# Are VirtualBox VMs shareable between Windows profiles?

Tags: virtualbox

I was setting up a VM on someone's computer with a view to installing software that only runs on Unix*, but under my profile (a Windows machine), but the person for whom it needs to be for can't see this VM when they open up VirtualBox.
Yes or no, is it possible to configure the VM or VirtualBox so that all users on that computer have access to that VM? Or are VMs profile specific? What should I have done to set up the VM for all users, or should I scrap that idea and just move on to setting up the software on an external server?

Comment: so you can add existing VMs to VirtualBox Manager. When you create a VM, it is added to VirtualBox Manager automatically, but for another user to see it in the Manager application, they must add it, from the menu `Machine > Add ` and browsing to the VMs .vbox or .xml file.  Note however that you will not be able to easily share a Running VM. Virtualbox runs within the users session unless you are using a headless configuration of some kind; you will have to shut down the VM when you log out as user A, and then start it up when you login to user B.

Comment: @kearly - What is wrong with the answer?

Comment: Nothing, I keep upvoting it to 2 and it keeps going back down to 1. I also accepted it as the correct answer, but it looks like it didn't process that properly. Odd. Trying again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yes or no, is it possible to configure the VM or VirtualBox so that
> all users on that computer have access to that VM?

Yes it is. The best approach is to keep Virtual Machines in a neutral folder such as C:\Virtual Machines .  Default folder is in USERS and that is why they are usually not shareable to other users of the same system.

Another location you can use and share is USERS\Public.

That should solve your issue.